# Icon used in file associations not found by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I added an icon for my file association in my C# WinForms project under Project Settings -> Publish -> Options -> File Associations and ran into the following error:

```
Error   1   The default icon [file path] could not be found in the current file references or is not part of the required download group. The default icon file name is case sensitive so the file name referenced in the application manifest must exactly match the icon's file name.
```

The icon is already added as a resource under my Project Settings -> Resources section.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the icon file under the Solution Explorer, right click it and select Properties, and then under Build Action choose "Content"